# How do I turn off tabs in VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

In VMware Workstation, tabs take up a lot of vertical space which could be better dedicated to the VM.

How can I trim the UI components of VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 1):

in Version 6.5, 7 and 7.1

Go to view > un-select "tabs".

[image: Tabs selection in main menu of VM Workstation]

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Preferences (Or Ctrl + P)

Uncheck -> Show aero peek thumbnails for open tabs

[Example Picture](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/10/b83220535c1c3d81f6603cafdb418a6b.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Version 12.5.9:

View -> Customize -> Deselect Tabs

[image]